# Is there a way to edit the icons used in the components?

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Long story short, I have a react + typescript app running in a network with very strict firewall rules. In the past this has caused issues when using fluentUI icons in custom components in my app because we could not reach out to the CDN in order to get the icons, so they would not display. I have found a workaround that involves storing the icons locally.

I am also using a few toolkit components, but these icons are not displaying, such as the 'x' next to a person in a people-picker to unselect them. My guess is that behind the scenes, these are using a similar if not the same method of reaching out to a CDN to get the icons necessary for each component.

Is there any way to get around this?

I have looked into the documentation and haven't found anything regarding editing the icons.

Answer (score 0):

What version of mgt are you using? As of `v3.0.0-preview.1`, the said icon has been updated to an svg and I think you won't have the same issue when you try it out.